# Chinese time string for ruby class time

Tags: ruby, parsing

When using stfrtime

I am having some issues in defining the string for chinese date formats like this:

28/4/16, 下午6:03

Where basically 上午 is am and 下午 is pm.

I have tried %y/%m/%d, %p%I:%M but that does not seem to work.

How do I set the locale or make the chinese AM / PM work?

Thank you very much in advance for your response!

Have a great one!

Comment: What method are you using? `strptime`? Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Can you `gsub` those two terms into `am` and `pm` or set your locale? Unless `strftime` outputs in those characters your locale is incorrect. See also: [I18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n).